# How to get a list of available Google Calendars via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-api

I want to write a basic web app via JavaScript to facilitate the generation of Google Calendar events based on ticket due dates.

My idea:

1. A user can select from a list of their own subscribed Google Calendars
2. Upon selection, the rest of my code would pull ticket due dates from the database, then execute an API call to Google and generate a calendar event based upon those dates.

I have successfully gotten the latter part of this to work, but I would like to avoid having to prompt the user with a `CalendarID`.  Rather, have them select it from a dynamic list that is generated.

Does anyone have any demo JavaScript code that would show how to generate a list of currently available Google Calendars which the user has modify permissions?  Basically, I'm going to want to return the `CalendarID` of whatever they select.

**Update:**

Here's the code that generates a list of events (assuming authentication has occured and works):

```
function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        'calendarId': 'primary'
        //'calendarId': calendarId
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
        for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');

            console.log(resp.items[i].summary + ' ' + resp.items[i].id);
        }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: sorry but i am misunderstanding but i do not understand this "I'm not a developer" and "I want to write a basic web app" its sounds like a my mom want to repair cars but she is not a car mechanists...

Comment: That really wasn't the question.  Do you know or do you not?  I just need a nudge in the right direction, not commentary on my background.

Comment: Please post relevant code. (Don't dump all of it here though, just enough to reproduce the issue.) Also, a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) would be a good idea.

Comment: @jsve: That's just it, I'm not sure even where to start.  I don't have issues with getting events.  Documentation that I'm finding is referring to listing event details, like here: [link] (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list).  Digging a bit deeper, this looks promising [link] (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get), but it returns data about a single calendar.  Not sure how to iterate all of them.  All I need is a pointer in the right direction and I can take it from there.

Comment: I could do a JSFiddle, but it would essentially be pulling a listing of events, which I'm not sure would be totally helpful at this point...yet?